# How to check whether td contain "NA" value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to check my table column and if the column contains "NA" value then I need to hide the table row.

Here is the JS code I tried.

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(2)").contains("NA", function (){
   ("table tr").hide(); 
});
```

Here is the table will look like:

```
Opti_Mi_Learning_Linear_Pro:        2
Opti_Mi_Learning_Quadratic_Pro:     1
Opti_Mi_Learning_Integer_Pro:       na
Opti_Mi_Learn:                      1
Opti_Mi_Learn_Evolu_Algo:           na
Opti_Mi_Lear_Neural_Networks:       na
```

Can somebody help me to correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `.filter()`:

```
$("table tr").filter(function () {
  return $.trim( $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text() ) === "NA";
}).hide();
```

Comment: Because your callback `function () { ("table tr").hide(); }` is wrong. You mean `$("table tr")`, but more importantly, `$("table tr")` would affect *all* `<tr>` on the page. You *actually* mean `$(this).closest("tr").hide()`. In any case it's more efficient to select the correct `<tr>` elements and hide them together, like I did, instead of hiding them one by one, like you attempted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Something like this:

```
$('table td:nth-child(2):contains("na")').parent().hide();
```

Note that the selector is case sensitive, so you'll have to put "na" in the right case.

Comment: Also, `contains` does what it says. It also would match `nature` or `navy`. That's probably not helpful.

Comment: If his example data is representative then it's fine, no integers contain the string "na".

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the text of the element and then use a string check, e.g.:

```
if ($("table tr td:nth-child(2)").text().indexOf("NA") !== -1) {
     // ...it contains NA, possibly with text before and/or after...
}
```

or

```
if ($("table tr td:nth-child(2)").text() === "NA") {
     // ...it's *exactly* the text "NA" ...
}
```

Both of the above checks are case-sensitive. To make them case-insensitive, just put `.toUpperCase()` after `.text()`.

Comment: note that `.text()` effectively only returns the text of the *first* `td` found.